# Is there a way to add a number in a number separated by commas using regex in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a specific number to a number in HTML div separated with commas, another variation of this [Is there any way to add number separated in html using regex and jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72130281/is-there-any-way-to-add-number-separated-in-html-using-regex-and-jquery)

Here is my trial code:

```
<div id="u-g-wb-break-word">150,452,032.32</div>
<div id="u-g-wb-break-word">455,666.67</div>
<div id="u-g-wb-break-word">977,435,787.992</div>
var a=$('#u-g-wb-break-word').text();
a=a.replace(/\,/g,'');
a=parseInt(a,10) + 17000;
console.log(a);
$('#u-g-wb-break-word').text(function(i, s) {
  return numberWithCommas(s.replace(/^[0-9,]*/g, a));
});

function numberWithCommas(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
}
```

I am getting my desired output but only for the first div with one number.

the output of the above code is -

```
150,469,032.32
455,666.67
977,435,787.992
```

But I want to add it to every number. Is there any way to perform it in one regex? As mentioned in the above question link. If not what is the best way to do it. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "*the output of the above code is...But I want to add it to every number.*" - great, so can you show the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use class, not id, as id must be unique within document:

```js
$('.u-g-wb-break-word').text((i, s) => new Intl.NumberFormat().format(parseFloat(s.replaceAll(',',''))+1700));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="u-g-wb-break-word">150,452,032.32</div>
<div class="u-g-wb-break-word">455,666.67</div>
<div class="u-g-wb-break-word">977,435,787.992</div>
```

Comment: The expected answer is 150,469,032.32 , 4,72,666.66, 97,74,52,787.992. But it is giving 3955.982

Comment: @TrippyZoro if you add every number - you will get 3955

Comment: How can I get the desired output 150,469,032.32 , 4,72,666.66, 97,74,52,787.992. What do I have to change in the code? As I want to add a specific number (here 17000) to all the numbers in different div's in HTML

Comment: @TrippyZoro oh, you want to convert string to number and add to each separate one, updated answer